# Angular mat-tree dataSource not keeping references on the original data

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-material, angular-cdk

I have extended this [Angular Material tree example](https://material.angular.io/cdk/tree/examples#cdk-tree-nested) to take an `Observable` as the source instead of static data:

**HTML**

```
<cdk-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
  <!-- This is the tree node template for leaf nodes -->
  <cdk-nested-tree-node *cdkTreeNodeDef="let node" class="example-tree-node">
    <!-- use a disabled button to provide padding for tree leaf -->
    <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
    {{node.name}}
    <button (click)="testClick(node)">TEST</button>
  </cdk-nested-tree-node>
  <!-- This is the tree node template for expandable nodes -->
  <cdk-nested-tree-node
    *cdkTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild"
    class="example-tree-node"
  >
    <button
      mat-icon-button
      [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.name"
      cdkTreeNodeToggle
    >
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    {{node.name}}
    <div [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
      <ng-container cdkTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
    </div>
  </cdk-nested-tree-node>
</cdk-tree>
```

**TypeScript**

```
interface FoodNode {
  name: string;
  children?: FoodNode[];
}

const TREE_DATA: FoodNode[] = [
  {
    name: 'Fruit',
    children: [
      {name: 'Apple'},
      {name: 'Banana'},
      {name: 'Fruit loops'},
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Vegetables',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Green',
        children: [
          {name: 'Broccoli'},
          {name: 'Brussels sprouts'},
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'Orange',
        children: [
          {name: 'Pumpkins'},
          {name: 'Carrots'},
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
];

/**
 * @title Tree with nested nodes
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-tree-nested-example',
  templateUrl: 'cdk-tree-nested-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-tree-nested-example.css'],
})
export class CdkTreeNestedExample {
  treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<FoodNode> (node => node.children);
  dataSource = of(TREE_DATA);
  dataSourceLast: any;

  constructor() {
    this.dataSourceLast = this.dataSource.pipe(publishReplay(1));

    this.dataSourceLast.connect();
  }

  hasChild = (_: number, node: FoodNode) => !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;

  testClick(node) {
    this.dataSourceLast.subscribe(data => this.findNode(data, node));
  }

  findNode(data, node) {
    console.log('search')
    if(data instanceof Array) {
      return data.some(x => this.findNode(x, node));
    } else {
      return data === node || data.children && this.findNode(data.children, node);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm expecting the `findNode` function to return the actual node in the data, but it doesn't, as you can see in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jutzkg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-tree-nested-example.ts).

However, this version works:

```
interface FoodNode {
  name: string;
  children?: FoodNode[];
}

const TREE_DATA: FoodNode[] = [
  {
    name: 'Fruit',
    children: [
      {name: 'Apple'},
      {name: 'Banana'},
      {name: 'Fruit loops'},
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Vegetables',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Green',
        children: [
          {name: 'Broccoli'},
          {name: 'Brussels sprouts'},
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'Orange',
        children: [
          {name: 'Pumpkins'},
          {name: 'Carrots'},
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
];

/**
 * @title Tree with nested nodes
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-tree-nested-example',
  templateUrl: 'cdk-tree-nested-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-tree-nested-example.css'],
})
export class CdkTreeNestedExample {
  treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<FoodNode> (node => node.children);
  dataSource = new ArrayDataSource(TREE_DATA);

  hasChild = (_: number, node: FoodNode) => !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;

  testClick(node) {
    console.log(this.findNode(TREE_DATA, node));
  }

  findNode(data, node) {
    console.log('search')
    if(data instanceof Array) {
      return data.some(x => this.findNode(x, node));
    } else {
      return data === node || data.children && this.findNode(data.children, node);
    }
  }
}
```

Why the references to the original data get lost when there's an `Observable` involved? I need this to work because I'm using [`SelectionModel`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/collections/api#SelectionModel) to manage checkboxes in the tree and I can't initialize it because of this references issue.